# Attribute error: Rich comparison configuration

Tags: python

I have a class `Point` with `x`and `y` attributes. I'd like to get `False` comparing a `Point` object with any other type of object. For instance, `Point(0, 1) == None` fails:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The class:

```
class Point():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

How do I configure `__eq__`to get `False` in comparison with any other object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Point):
        return False
    try:
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

First check the type and return False if its not a Point instance. We do this in case they are comparing some other type that happens to have an `x` or `y` attribute but isn't necessarily the same context.

Second catch an attribute error, just in case someone subclasses Point and removes the attribute or changes Point in some way.

Comment: If it's a Point instance, surely it should have the attributes? If someone removes the attribute, wouldn't it be better just to let it complain?

Comment: @MRAB: That depends on what the OP wants for the behavior. The OP asked to return False if the instance are not equal. Not raise an exception. I consider it not equal, if they don't have matching attributes.  An exception is already what the OP said they didnt want.  No exceptions to catch.

Comment: @MRAB: All three of our answers take different points of view. The OP can choose the handling they want

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see whether the other object acts like a `Point` object instead of rejecting all non-`Point` objects:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
  try:
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
  except AttributeError:
    return False
```

That way `Point(1, 1) == Vector(1, 1)`, in case you use coordinate vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Point) and self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```